# Want to put Json into array?

Tags: javascript, json

I have this request from an API

http://api.koordinates.com/api/vectorQuery.json/?key=78582ad1ffea4388813d19ab9b5a2b63&layer=144&x=174.6964&y=-41.3768&geometry=true&radius=100000&max_results=100

Which I want to put in an array in JS.

How do I do this?

Help would be appreciated, mind me if I don't know much about Json as Im a Designer.

Comment: What do you mean by an array? Because from what I'm seeing, the data is in an object format.

Comment: As I said I don't really know what I'm doing and would just like a point in the right direction :)

Comment: Just as an fyi, JSON is a javascript object. So if you have access to this response in your javascript file, you can access any of the data as if you would an object. May want to read up a bit on accessing attributes in json.

Comment: @TimMashinter: FYI, JSON is *not* a JavaScript object. It's a set of UTF-8 encoded textual data, formatted to conform to the requirements of JSON. In JavaScript, it would be represented as a String.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things, that is a boatload of json, and you are asking a loaded question. Glancing at it in VIM i'm just going to guess that you want the 'features' array. A naive answer would be you have the object in say something called 'response' then you would want to pullout response.features.  I'm suspecting you are asking for more and for that I would direct you to a library like jquery. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ you may want to find that javascript friend to help set you up. Also, there could be issues with cross-origin requests that you need to deal with.

hope this helps